# Understanding backprop for softmax

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation, cs231n

I'm looking on a given [solution](https://gitlab.com/me-learnz/CS231n/blob/master/assignment1/cs231n/classifiers/neural_net.py) of the first assignment of cs231n course.

Down below a snippet from the loss function.
I don't really understand lines `140-143`. Can you explain why `dscores` (the derivative of `scores`) is calculated like that?

[image]

Comment: What is `y`? and `N` in conjunction to `lim_scores`?

Comment: I was looking for the answer to this as well. I think the answer is in section `Computing the Analytic Gradient with Backpropagation` of this [link](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-case-study/).

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that posting code in images very annoying to copy/paste and it's bad for web reference ment.

This is due to the derivative of the softmax, but to me it's seems fishy.

If $S$ is the softmax vector, then the Jacobian $DS$ consists of $S_j(\delta_{ij}-S_i)$. This could explain the `-=1` part, but not the `/=N`, and not the shape either.